# Не обновляется nodejs

Tags: node.js

Выполнил эти команды:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f  
sudo npm install -g n  
sudo n stable
```

`node -v` показывает `4.6.2` а должно быть не меньше `8.0.0` или я ошибаюсь?

`sudo node -v` же выводит `8.0.0`, как и ожидается, но почему только с `sudo`?

Comment: А `sudo node -v`?

Comment: при такой команде 8.0.0. А с чем это связано?

Comment: `n stable` (без `sudo`) работает?

Comment: ошибку не выводило

Comment: Повлияло на вывод `node -v`?

Comment: понял вас, получилось

Answer (score 0):

Какая система?
В Ubuntu например разные ветки есть, 6.*, 7.*, 8.* и т.д. Также есть инструмент, позволяющий этим управлять. Нода версии (например) 6.3.1 может обновиться до 6.3.2, несмотря на то, что есть уже 7.*, 8.* и т.д.

Comment: `n` и есть этот инструмент.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте снести старую версию и добавить вручную репозитории для новой ветки (на момент установки можно отключить все остальные, потом включить):

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | -E bash –
```

Полагаю дело в том, что в вашем списке репозиториев есть только старые списки нода (такое часто встречается, если не прописать репозиторий нода вручную).

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo n stable
```

О, у вас [`n`](https://github.com/tj/n). Менеджер версий, исполненный по технологии "поставь нужную версию в домашнюю папку и подмени переменные среды, чтобы эта версия использовалась по умолчанию", что удобно для разработки. Из этой же серии RVM, rbenv, GVM.

Дело в том, что `sudo` начинает новую шелл-сессию от лица другого пользователя. В данном случае `root`. И изменения конфигурации (новые установленные версии, версия по умолчанию) сохраняются в его папках и актуальны только для шелл-сессий от его лица (или с его конфигурацией; я ни разу и не видел, чтобы так делали, но не вижу, что мешает).

**Используя `n` с `sudo`, вы меняете среду для `root`, а не для себя.**